# Python xlrd Exception: Unknown cell type 'n+'

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlrd

I have a python script that downloads an xlsx file and parses the contents, however it's started failing at the line

```
 workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)
```

with the error "Exception: Unknown cell type 'n+' in rowx=1 colx=4"

Can anyone point me in the right direction with regards to what the n+ cell type is or how to move past this error

Alternatively if anyone knows of a python module that will read an xlsx file without tripping over this cell value.

Cheers

-- EDIT --

After unzipping the file I found this in the xml of the worksheet

```
<c r="E2" t="n+"><v>18</v></c>
```

Comment: Can you maybe also provide the XSLX you are passing to your open_workbook() function or at least the part that is mentioned in the exception message? It seems to me that the error is coming from there. There is a similar issue but with ISO dates mentioned at https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/issues/86

Comment: I can't provide the file and have no control over it contents or formatting, I've added more information to the question

Comment: What happens if you open the document *In Excel*? Is there something special about cell E2?

Comment: The file opens as normal in excel. Cell E2 is a number formatted as a string.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution although it's not ideal...

I've changed the xlrd code to accept t="n+" and process it as t="n" which is a number it's a bit hacky but I can't find anything online relating to t="n2"

Comment: I think this is, in fact, related to the [bug](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/issues/86) linked in the comments above. Probably a file written (badly) by some non-Excel application in Strict XML Mode. The `"n+"` type doesn't exist in the Office Open XML File Format, as defined [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm). So your solution is probably the best, if you have no control over the creation of the source file.

Comment: Thanks mate , useful link